# jquery: add #hash to all links if it doesn't already have one?

Tags: jquery, hash, addition

hey guys,
the following code works fine... I'm adding a #wpf-wrapper hash to all links that are inside of #wpf-wrapper.

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a').live('click',function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#wpf-wrapper");        
});
```

However if there is a link that already has e.g. `href="#"` I don't want to add another one to it. Why is the following code not working?

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a').not('#wpf-wrapper a[href="#"]').live('click',function() 
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#wpf-wrapper");        
});
```

Suddenly none of my links gets this #wpf-wrapper added?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to do this in the click handler instead of up front?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This selector is wrong

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a').not('#wpf-wrapper a[href="#"]')
```

should be this using the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) with a proper `:not()` selector

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a:not([href*="#"])')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a').each(function(){ 
    if( !this.hash ) this.hash = "#wpf-wrapper";
});
```

You can use the native `hash` property on the `a` element to set it instead of using jQuery's `.attr()` method.

---

If the reason you're doing this inside the click handler, is that an `.each()` doesn't work, it's likely that you're running the code before the DOM is loaded.

If so, do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#wpf-wrapper a').each(function(){ 
        if( !this.hash ) this.hash = "#wpf-wrapper";
    });
});
```

If you're creating the elements dynamically, add the hash when they're being created.